# How to add HyperLink in ModelState.AddModelError

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i want to add a hyperlink in my message like

```
ModelState.AddModelError("_FORM", "Please report this error <a href="asdf.aspx">Click Here</a>");
```

Im using asp.net mvc 2. How can i do this?

Comment: Write your own Html.ValidationMessage() and Html.ValidationSummary() that will not encode messages. That's relatively easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `ValidationMessage` and `ValidationSummary` methods internally use the [SetInnerText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tagbuilder.setinnertext.aspx) method which automatically encodes the values you have saved in the Model Errors.

Like queen3 suggests, you'll have to write your own versions of these methods to overcome this.

You can see original methods in [the MVC2 source code here](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742).

Replace `tagNameHere.SetInnerText(value)` with `tagNameHere.InnerHtml = value`

**Important Note:** Please make sure you take great care with where the information displayed in these messages comes from, you're allowing html now, so you're susceptible to [Cross Site Scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)